# How to use system images in image slider instead of links in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using an image slider in my react native app, currently I am using web links of images to show the slider, but I want to use a custom image like my own images that I have in my assets folder. how can I use these images please help here is my code.

```js
<ImageSlider
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  style={styles.imageOpacity}
  images={[
    "https://placeimg.com/640/640/nature",
    "https://placeimg.com/640/640/people",
    "https://placeimg.com/640/640/animals",
    "https://placeimg.com/640/640/beer"
  ]}
/>
```

I want to use my custom images instead of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native provides a unified way of managing images and other media assets in your iOS and Android apps. To add a static image to your app, place it somewhere in your source code tree and reference it like this:

`<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />`

A complete guide present [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images)

Or you can do this:

```
<ImageSlider
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    style={styles.imageOpacity}
                    images={[
                     require('../assets/img/art_1.png'),
                     require('../assets/img/art_2.png'),
                     require('../assets/img/art_3.png'),          
                   ]} 
                  />
```

Let me know if it worked.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403384/react-native-image-slider-cannot-display-local-images)

Answer (score 2):

You need to import images from assets and then pass it to component.

```
import Img01 from 'path-to-img1.png'
import Img02 from 'path-to-img2.png'

[...]

const images = [Img01, Img02]

[...]

<ImageSlider
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  style={styles.imageOpacity}
  images={images}
/>
```